# Select first item in ListView by default, MVVM, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I am writing some programm where is possible to select device and later configure it. I implemented ListView where all device are listed. I like that first device is selected by default. How to do that? I try several solution found on StackOverflow and over Google but without luck.

Here is my code in XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvdevices" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding devicelist}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice}" DataContext="{Binding }">
       <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridDevices">
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="DeviceId" Header="DeviceId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceId}" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="NameId" Header="NameId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NameId}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="ManufacturerId" Header="ManufacturerId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManufacturerId}" Width="150"/>
               </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I dont know how to implement that first item is selected by default when is connected. It is also possibility that no device will found, what then? Please for help! If and question please ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you populate your `devicelist`, you can set the `SelectedDevice` to be the first item in the device list, or `null` if there is nothing in the list.

```
using System.Linq;

...

SelectedDevice = devicelist.FirstOrDefault();
```

Assuming that `SelectedDevice` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, this should then select the first item on your view.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel, you just need to set your `SelectedDevice` to the first item (and of course trigger a `OnPropertyChanged`)